# How to insert cons into list on lisp?

Tags: lisp

```
  1 (setq R (cons 1 20))
  2 (setq L (cons 5 '(a b)))
  3 (setq U (cons 10 'h))
  4
  5
  6 (defun insertcell(R L)
  7   (setq x (list r l))
  8   (cond ((< (car R) (car L))
  9                  (setq x (list R L))
  10                 (print x)
  11                 (print (car(car(cdr x))))
  12         ((> (car R) (car L)
  13                  (insertcell R (car(cdr x)))))      
  14 ))
  15
  16
  17 (print r)
  18 (print l)
  19 (insertcell r l)
  20 (insertcell u r)
  21
```

Q1) I don't know how to return function's return value/

Q2) About upper code, 
   for example, I have a list , K= ((1.20)(5 A B))
   and I want to add a (3.H). 
   So, K= ((1.20)(3.H)(5 A B))

looking my code, 
     *** - SYSTEM::%EXPAND-FORM: (> (CAR R) (CAR L)) should be a lambda expression.

What is this? , I searched on stackflow, but I didn't solve the error.

*** Lisp is many difficult. 
I studied that C , C++  assembly and ruby and I can code that languages. But, I'm very confused because of Lisp.

Comment: Without proper indentation and code formatting you won't get far in any programming language. You might want to format and indent your code. Always. Bonus for Lisp: a good editor can indent the code for you.

Comment: It's also fully unclear what your code should do. 'insertcell' ? What is `3.H`? `1.20` is a number. But `3.H`???

Answer (score 0):

In lisp you just need to type the expression to get a return value. Think of functions as solving an equation with parens.

For `(2 + 3) / 5` you would solve `(2 + 3)` before you divide by `5` to get the result, the same for lisp expressions. `(/ (+ 2 3) 5)` is the same expression and evaluates to `1`. Think of it as reducing an equation until it's solved. e.g:

```
(/ (+ 2 3) 5) ;   
(/ 5 5)       ; since `2 + 3` is `5` we replace `(+ 2 3)` with `5`
=> 1          ; "return" value/result of expression
```

So the insert function itself is just:

```
(define (insert pos item xs)
    (cond ((null? xs) (cons item '())) ; create a list if passed null else
          ((= pos 0) (cons item xs))     ; if (n = 0) insert `item' else next
          (cons (car xs) (insert (- pos 1) item (cdr xs)))))
```

Where we traverse the list and decrement `n` until it equals `0`. We then use `cons` to add `item` to the list.

The traversal would look like this in C:

```
void insert(size_t position,void *item,struct List *list){
    if(list==NULL){
        cons(item,NULL);
    } else {
    if(n==0){
        cons(item,list->tail);
    } else {
        cons(list->head, insert(position - 1, item, list->tail));
    }}
}
```

Where `struct List` is:

```
struct List{
    void *car;
    void *cdr;
};
```

---

Lambdas are just functions without names which you can pass around as if they were data. They are similar to function pointers in C where you can write a higher-order function like `map(void (*f)(void*),struct *list);` which would apply `f` to every member of the list.

In Lisp:

```
(define (map f xs)
    (if (null? xs) ; if empty return empty else apply `f'
        '()        ; and go to next node
        (cons (f (car xs)) (map f (cdr xs)))))
```

In C:

```
void map(void (*f)(void*),struct List *list){
    if(list==NULL)return;
    list->car = f(list->car);
    map(f,(struct List*)list->cdr)
}
```

Where if you have a list of 1..10 and you write `(map (lambda (x) (+ 1 x)) xs)` you would be adding `1` to every member of the list, resulting in a list of the numbers 2..11.

Note: Scheme Lisp was used for the above examples. You should take a look at 'Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs' (SICP) which is a brilliant introduction to both lisp and computer science.

Comment: @RainerJoswig fixed, just swap `n` with `pos` (originally wrote with `n` but changed to `pos` to make it easier to understand)

Answer (score 0):

The first branch of your `cond` in your `insertcell` function is missing a closing parenthesis. It should be:

```
(defun insertcell (R L)
  (setq x (list r l))
  (cond ((< (car R) (car L))
         (setq x (list R L))
         (print x)
         (print (car (car (cdr x)))))    ; <- add a closing paren on this line
        ((> (car R) (car L))             ; <- add a closing paren here too
         (insertcell R (car (cdr x))))))
```